# Powershell: Is there a way to enumerate access of a singular folder or file?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

A question was run by me from a user to disclose who had access to a specific folder.

I've tried this script and received the correct permissions on the folders but the current script includes all subfolders and files and generates large output.

```
$path = "\\fs1\" #define path to the shared folder
$reportpath ="C:\temp\ACL.csv" #define path to export permissions report
#script scans for directories under shared folder and gets acl(permissions) for all of them
dir -Recurse $path | where { $_.PsIsContainer } | % { $path1 = $_.fullname; Get-Acl $_.Fullname | % { $_.access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty '.\Application Data' -Value $path1 -passthru }} | Export-Csv $reportpath
```

I've tried to run a singular query on AD but it doesn't show me correct ACL entries. Is there a way to only query the singular folder/file? A query like this would help for future requests.

Comment: Remove the -recurse switch on dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon.) for your comment. I did repro as suggested by you and found the expected output.

**PowerShell Command**

```
$path = "C:\Users\" #define path to the shared folder
$reportpath ="C:\temp\ACL.txt" #define path to export permissions report
#script scans for directories under shared folder and gets acl(permissions) for all of them
dir $path | where { $_.PsIsContainer } | % { $path1 = $_.fullname; Get-Acl $_.Fullname | % { $_.access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty '.\Application Data' -Value $path1 -passthru }} | Export-Csv $reportpath
```

[image]

**OUTPUT-**
[image]